# How can a federated SAML authentication flow can work?

Tags: authentication, saml, federation

I'd like to setup an integration with a third party vendor for which I have to provide services, which need to be customer-aware.

The main flow is on the third party, that already have a service provider and an identity provider; the third party service provider then have to call my service, but then I need to check the authentication, for which I would like to rely on their identity provider, gaining so also access to the user identity (name, mail, other data).

basic flow

[image: 1]

Does a flow like this can work? Do I have to receive the authentication infos cookie? Are other ways for which I can integrate with the third party identity provider?

Answer (score 0):

Current web standards would likely dictate [OIDC](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html), especially if you want your service to be open to direct consumers as opposed to, or in addition to enterprise users. Were I building something today, I would choose to build out only OIDC, because it doesn't limit the Identity Providers I may want to use. In addition to enterprise, you could consider social logins as well, such as Facebook, Google, etc. If your users are **ONLY** enterprise users, then yes, you could consider SAML.

The identity data is usually returned to you in a JSON Web Token, or JWT.

I would suggest looking at OIDC implementations on your favorite stack, or look to a cloud provider.